# iOS Launch Screen File not updating with new project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, launch-screen

I made a new project(Swift) to completely upgrade a legacy app (ObjC).  The upgrade is fine, but still seeing the old Launch Screen.  Is there anyway to reset that (other than reinstalling).

Comment: this question needs more detail & context:  does the new project completely replace the legacy app?  Or does the new project incorporate everything from the legacy app (i.e. it includes all the objective c source code)?  is the new project working in every other way except the Launch Screen?

Comment: Have you tried looking at your target's settings under General where it says "App Icons and Launch Images" (Look at "Launch Screen File")? Don't see how this has anything to do with switching from Objective C to Swift.

Comment: It is a completely new project using the same bundle id.  All new code, nothing from the old app.

Comment: I have the same problem like you described. Could you solve that issue?

Comment: Just delete the old app from your device and delete derived data, then clear your project and run again ! It is a problem of cash !

Comment: That does work. But this is not a solution for an app update with 1.5 million users. Interesting point, deploying via xcode the old version after a clean xcode deploy of the new version replaces the new launchscreen with the old one. Unfortunately not the other way round. Any ideas?

Comment: No I think it is a local cache problem, don't worry for app store it will work.

Comment: I don't think so. Device running iOS 10, app update replaces launchscreen as expected. iOS 11, 12, 13 not.